# Why Error() in aov() gives three levels?

Tags: r, anova

I'm trying to understand how to properly run an Repeated Measures or Nested ANOVA in R, without using mixed models. From consulting tutorials, the formula for a one-variable repeated measures anova is:

```
aov(Y ~ IV+ Error(SUBJECT/IV) )
```

where IV is the within subjects and subject is the identity of the subjects. However, most examples show outputs with two strata: Error:subject and Error: subject:WS. Meanwhile I am getting three strata ( Error:subject and Error: subject:WS, Error:within). Why do I have three strata, when I'm trying to specify only two (Within and Between)?

Here is an reproducible example:

```
data(beavers)
id = rep(c("beaver1","beaver2"),times=c(nrow(beaver1),nrow(beaver2)))
data = data.frame(id=id,rbind(beaver1,beaver2))
data$activ=factor(data$activ)
aov(temp~activ+Error(id/activ),data=data)
```

temp is a continuous measure of temperature, id is the identity of the beaver activ is binary factor for activity. The output of the model is:

```
Error: id
      Df Sum Sq Mean Sq
activ  1  28.74   28.74

Error: id:activ
           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
activ      1 15.313  15.313   18.51  0.145
Residuals  1  0.827   0.827               

Error: Within
           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Residuals 210   7.85 0.03738
```